# If $f: U \to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic and $h: f(U) \to \mathbb{R}$ is harmonic, then $h \circ f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ is harmonic.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation

This is a corollary from my class. The proof contains a few claims whose derivation l'd like to see in details, to make sure I'm not missing out on anything.

> **Corollary:** If $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic and $h: f(U) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is harmonic, then $h \circ f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is harmonic.
>
> **Proof:** Let $z_{0} \in U$. On an open neighborhood of $f\left(z_{0}\right), h$ is a real part of a suitable holomorphic
>   function $H$ (claim 1). By the chain rule, $H \circ f$ is holormorphic on a
>   small neighborhood of $z_{0}$ (claim 2). $Re(H \circ f)=h \circ f$
>   (claim 3 ) is harmonic (claim 4).

Claims 1 and 4 are from previous materials which I have understood. I tried to show claim 2 by applying the Cauchy-Riemann equations to $H \circ f$, but not sure that I got it right. As this is my first attempt to do calculus after a while, please keep the proof at the 1st-2nd year undergrad level if possible.

Comment: Are you asking why the composition of holomorphic functions is holomorphic?

Comment: I'd like to see the derivation by the chain rule that shows $H \circ f$ is holomorphic, and why $Re(H \circ f) = h \circ f$.

Comment: $H=h+ik$ where $h,k$ are real valued then. Then $$Re(H\circ f)=Re(h\circ f + i k\circ  f)=h\circ f$$

Comment: Real-valued harmonic functions (like your $h \circ f$) are just those functions that arise as the real parts of holomorphic functions -at least locally. This explains the strategy of proof. Just do what the proof says for (2): take the derivative of $H \circ f$ with respect to $\overline{z}$ and you will see that you get zero if you apply the chain rule.

Comment: I'm relearning stuffs from my undergrad days, so I would appreciate if the long form could be written out, so that I can check every step and be confident that they make sense to me.